# VFP repeat from a SOQL in APex

Tags: apex, repeat, visualforce

I have an Apex class with a SOQL:

```
Account_Statement__c statement = [Select Id, Name,(Select Id, Invoice__c, Invoice__r.Name from Account_Statement_Items__r) from Account_Statement__c where Id != null limit 1];
```

When system debug, everything is working as expected.

In my VFP, I have an Apex repeat. I can only display the value from the `Account_Statement__c`
I am trying to go in the related record but it is not working.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!RefAccountStatement}" var="line" >
                         <tr style="line-height:1">
                            <td class="no" style="width:10px; height:15px;">{!i}</td>
                            <td class="desc" style="width:30%; height:10px;"><h3>{!line.Name}</h3><p>{!line.Invoice__c}</p></td>...
```

What am I missing? new to coding... Thanks

Comment: Your query only returns one Account_statement__c so you don't need to iterate on that one record.  (You also don't need to check if a record has an Id in SOQL, they all do.) I'm guessing your apex repeat value should be RefAccountStatement.Account_Statement_Items__r but without the relevant apex code that is a bit of guess.

Comment: Thanks Kasper, here is the full class: public class viewPDFToAccountStatement {
    public List<Account_Statement__c> RefAccountStatement {get;set;}
    public viewPDFToAccountStatement(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {    
        standardPageController.addFields(new List<String>{'Id', 'Name'});
        RefAccountStatement = RetrieveAS();
    }
    public List<Account_Statement__c> RetrieveAS(){
       return [Select Name,(Select Invoice__c, Invoice__r.Name from Account_Statement_Items__r) from Account_Statement__c where Id != null limit 1];
    }
}

Comment: Trying that won't work in the VFP <apex:repeat value="{!RefAccountStatement.Account_Statement_Items__r}" var="line" >

Comment: Found it, needed to change the SOQL to this: return [Select Name, Invoice__r.Name, Account_Statement__r.Name from Statement_Item__c where Id != null limit 1]; and now I can use this:  <apex:repeat value="{!RefAccountStatement}" var="line" >
                             <tr style="line-height:1">
                                <td class="no" style="width:10px; height:15px;">{!i}</td>
                                <td class="desc" style="width:30%; height:10px;"><h3>{!line.Name}</h3><p>{!line.Invoice__r.Name}</p></td> thx!